# How long should I wait before fetching the "SENT" mailbox after sending an e-mail?

Tags: email, imap, smtp

I have made my e-mail client immediately fetch new e-mails from the IMAP server (only opening the "Sent"/"Sent mail" mailbox) right after a new e-mail has been sent.

To my (slight) surprise, no e-mail is fetched then. It seems to be "queued" and sent a little bit later, so my "clever" fetching of the sent mailbox is meaningless.

But how long do I have to wait? I always want to look at the "sent mail" in my e-mail client to see that my e-mail was really sent. How come it isn't instant? How many seconds should I wait before fetching?

Comment: The client copies the mail into the "sent" folder. Not the server. At least that is what I always see in Thunderbird. Which client are you using?

Comment: @zomega I've made my own. It bases all e-mails from what comes from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [IMAP IDLE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE). The server will tell you when there is a new message in the sent folder.

Do not ask the server for new messages (polling). Instead use the idle command.